# Ajax upload with InputFile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, upload, jsf-2.2

Trying to do an ajax upload with JSF inputFile

```
<h:body>
  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadController.upfile}">
         <f:ajax listener="#{uploadController.handleUpload}" />
      </h:inputFile>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

when i choose file, my page is refreshed with a javascript error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:2734

Getting same error with a simple inputText

```
<h:body>
  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h:inputText id="test" value="#{testController.test}">
         <f:ajax />
      </h:inputText>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

It's work when i remove enctype="multipart/form-data"

My JSF dependencies are

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Jsf js file loaded by browser [Download](http://speedy.sh/TD3bR/jsf.js)

Thanks

Comment: Do a hard refresh on the JS file. Apparently you've an older one still in browser cache.

Comment: thanks for answering. Js file is refreshed but still have an error. description updated for more details

Comment: Can you update with your taglib definitions?
Also, `f:ajax listener=''` is broken as far as I know.
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3018
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3048